# get selected text with taphold event

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to mark the text I have selected using the taphold event.
See the following code:

```
$(function () {

    $('body').bind('taphold', function (e) {
        $(this).addClass('highlighted');
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    });

});
```

But $(this) return the body, how can I get the selected content?

Answer (score 1):

As you bind the event with the `body` so `$(this)` will return the `body`, but `e.target` will return your target element on which you fire you event.

```
$(function () {
    $('body').bind('taphold', function (e) {
        $(e.target).addClass('highlighted');   // use e.target instead of this
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).delegate('Here it should be the text selector like id or class name ', 'taphold', function (e) {

```
             $(this).addClass('highlighted');
             e.stopImmediatePropagation();
             return false;
        });
```

Hope this is helpful.